# Is it possible to convert avro message to POJO similar to application/json to Pojo conversion?

Tags: avro, spring-cloud-stream

In my poc, I am using Spring cloud stream and connected to confluent schema registry. I can see schema's registered on schema registry, so I dont want to create own avro schema. I was able to get payload converted to POJO using application/json. Now I am trying to do the same with avro to Pojo conversion. But it doesnt seem to be working.

I am setting content type as ''contentType: application/*+avro''.

Any sample application, will be helpful.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is not enough information for anyone to help you; you need to show configuration and describe exactly what problem you are having. You also need to provide version information. Have you read [the documentation?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#schema-evolution).

Comment: Hi, here are some samples demonstrating how Schema Registry integration is working with Spring Cloud Stream. Please take a look and compare with your configuration. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/schema-registry-samples